# Simple Image of $R\rightarrow 2^R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Super simple example that I don't understand.. 
suppose [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLV0N.png). I thought the Im(f) would equal 2 to the Reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That isn't possible,  by (a generalized form of) Cantor's diagonal argument (the power set has higher cardinality).

$\operatorname{Im}f=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}(x,\infty)=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I think my basic understanding is very poor, if the mapping takes a a single element from domain R and maps to an ordered pair why/how is the image still R? (1 dimension?) maybe I don't understand what Image means ( thought it was range). Thanks again I really appreciate it

Comment: Sure.  Actually the image of $x\in\mathbb R$ is a _subset_, the interval from $x$ to $\infty$.  Recall, $2^{\mathbb R}$ is isomorphic to the set of all subsets of $\mathbb R$, also known as the power set...